# Need help to extend value to seconds

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

Got a calculated column with this formula:

```
=IF(INT(Minuter/60)<10;"0"&INT(Minuter/60);INT(Minuter/60))&":"&IF(ROUND((((Minuter/60)-INT(Minuter/60))*60);0)<10;"0"&ROUND((((Minuter/60)-INT(Minuter/60))*60);0);ROUND((((Minuter/60)-INT(Minuter/60))*60);0)))
```

"Minuter" is another calculated column with this formula:

```
=INT(([Column2]-[Column1])*1440)
```

So I got this results from this and i'm kinda pleased with it, but is there anyway to make it display seconds, can I extend the code somehow?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your description, my understanding is that you want to get the time between two date and makes it shows in this format : `hh:mm:ss`

Display in format `hh:mm`

```
=text(([Column2]-[Column1]),"hh:mm")
```

Display in format `hh:mm：ss`

```
=text(([Column2]-[Column1]),"hh:mm:ss")
```

Comment: Yes, thats the easy solution if I want it to display up to 24 hours. But I want it to exceed 24 hours and it works with the formula i've created above. But right now it only displays "hh:mm" but i would like it to displat "hh:mm:ss".